# How to make an efficient and fast mapping between owl classes and java classes?

Tags: java, mapping, ontology, owl-api

I'm trying to make an application that makes use of the Hermit OWL reasoner to reason on user input data. I've already made the mapping from OWL classes to Java classes and the other way by using the various OWLAPI methods.

The only thing left to do now is to make some kind of mapping that allows a Java program to automatically convert a lot of OWL individuals, extracted from the ontology, to the associated Java classes.

Currently I have the following in mind: a hashmap that contains a list of the names of the OWL classes as keys and then as value to the key the name of the Java class. When looking up a key, the class can then be instantiated through the use of Java Reflection. The only downside to this way is that it will probably be very slow?

Does anybody have a better idea to do the above?

Thanks in advance!

Tom DC

**EDIT:**

An example of an OWL class that I converted into a Java class (the class was too big to post here): http://pastebin.com/aEsjvDN7

As you can see in the example, I already tried to make it easier for a mapping by creating a function that looks at the OWL IRI and then decides what object it has to choose to make. This function is probably obsolete and useless when using JAXB or the hashmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to instantiate a particular Java class starting from a match in the map, I would put as values builders for these classes rather than class names to be built through reflection, since it gives you better flexibility and possibly better performances.

An example of such builders:

```
public interface BuilderClass<O, P>{
    O build(P parameter);
}

public class BuilderSpecificClass<SpecificClass, Object>{
    @Override
    public SpecificClass build(Object parameter){
        return new SpecificClass(parameter);
    }
}
```

Then the map would look something like:

```
Map<String, BuilderClass<SpecificClass, Object>> map=new HashMap<String, BuilderClass<SpecificClass, Object>>();
map.put("<class_iri>", new BuilderSpecificClass<SpecificClass, Object>());
```

That said, I'm not clear how your specific classes work, so there might be a better way. Can you add an example of how you built them?

Edited after Tom's extra details:

Ok, if I understand what your class is doing, you have half the approach I described already implemented.
Your class is basically wrapping sets of OWL assertion axioms, either asserted or inferred - i.e., values for your fields come either from the ontology or from a reasoner, and relate individuals with individuals or with values.
You also have methods to populate a class instance from an ontology and a reasoner; these correspond to what I proposed above as `build()` method, where the parameters would be the ontology and the reasoner. You can skip passing the ontology manager since an instance of OWLOntologyManager is already accessible through the ontology: `ontology.getOWLOntologyManager()`

What I would do here is create builders pretty much like I described and have them call your methods to populate the objects.

In terms of performances, it's hard to tell whether there are any serious hot spots - at a guess, there shouldn't be anything particularly hard in this code. The ontology is the place where such problems usually arise.
What I can suggest in this class is the following:

```
private final String personURI = ThesisOntologyTools.PERSON_URI + "Person";
```

You have a few member variables which look like this one. I believe these are constants, so rather than having a copy in each of your instances, you might save memory by making them static final.

```
OWLDataProperty isLocationConfirmed = dataFactory.getOWLDataProperty(IRI.create(isLocationConfirmedURI));
```

You are creating a number of objects in a way similar to this. Notice that `IRI.create()` will return an immutable object, as well as `dataFactory.getOWLDataProperty()`, so rather than accessing the data factory each time you can reuse such objects.
All objects produced by a data factory are not linked to a specific ontology and are immutable, so you can reuse them freely across your classes, to reduce the number of new objects created. A data factory might cache some of them, but some others might be recreated from scratch on each call, so reducing the number of calls should improve speed and memory requirements.

Other than this, the approach looks fine. If the memory required or the speed are too high (or too low), you may want to start using a profiler to pinpoint the issues. and if the hotspots are in the OWL API, please raise an issue [in OWLAPI issue tracker](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/issues) :-) we don't get enough performance reports from real users.

Comment: I'll edit my question and add a copy of an actual java class I made.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and suggestions. I'm going to try them out and post the results of the performance in this topic. This might take a while since the project is currently under review.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend strongly against Reflection, as powerful as it is, and recommend instead [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html). It allows you to derive Java classes based on XML schema, and OWL would just be a specific instance of that.

Otherwise, take a look on the web. I feel like you aren't the first to want such a thing.

Comment: If Tom has already implemented Java code using the OWL API, using JAXB will force him to redo a lot of work. I would not recommend this approach unless the one currently ongoing turns out to be completely unworkable.

Comment: Well, the point is to offer alternatives so he can weigh the pros and cons of each and make the right choice. If he was convinced of his approach, he wouldn't have posted. Besides, JAXB generates code, so it probably wouldn't be a huge effort to try it and see what happens.

Comment: I appreciate the alternative look on how to make the actual java classes for the owl versions. The situation at this moment is that I have a huge ontology (around 150 classes) that I have to use to reason on user data, but only a fraction (around 25) of the ontology is actually used. Therefor I only made the Java classes for the actual OWL classes that I will use in my program. The other classes are totally ignored and mean nothing for my application. Using JAXB will probably generate all classes for all the OWL classes, right?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I've never tried to limit the number, so I don't know if there is some configuration that allows it. I'm not sure how it would handle things where one class depends on another. Looking forward to more details on the approach suggested by @Ignazio.

Comment: I've edited my response after looking at the example class - I hope it helps.